# How to use two different tables for authentication process in spring boot application?

Tags: spring-boot, authentication, spring-security

I have two separate entities as below.

1. Customer
2. Admin

How do I manage authentication process for this two separate entities by spring security ? or is there any error with my approach ?

**Note : There is a total disjoint specialization as below.**

[image]

So when mapping this relation into schema it will generate two separate tables as Customer and Admin. That's why I can't use one entity to authenticate both type of users.

Comment: did you ever get this to work ?  I am running into the same issue at the moment.